# Ambiguous EventArgs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

After scouring SO and also reading about the EventArgs class from the Microsoft SDN archives, I am unsure of how the code below is getting its data.

I understand that EventArgs is just a parameter which contains the data, but I do not get *how* it has the data. The method below is called in the front via OnItemDataBound, that makes sense.

I have searched the code behind but there is no data binding for `ID="rptSectionDates"` so I am unsure how this is working.

**Question:** Can someone please tell me how `e.Item.DataItem` in the code behind has any data?

**EDIT:** Extending the front for further help.

**Front:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSections" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnItemDataBound="rptSections_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="section-information-wrapper">
        <div class="section-information-header">
            <div class="section-information-header-left">
                <h3>
                    <span class="section-information-crn-head"><a title="<%# GlobalHelper.GetSetting("Course.CRNToolTip") %>">CRN</a>: </span>
                    <span class="section-information-crn-number"><%# Eval("CRN") %></span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="section-information-header-right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-information-body">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="section-information-subheader">
                        <th class="section-information-date"><h4>Date(s)</h4></th>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phNonDistanceColumnHeaders" runat="server">
                            <th class="section-information-day"><h4>Day(s)</h4></th>
                            <th class="section-information-time"><h4>Time</h4></th>
                            <th class="section-information-building"><h4>Building</h4></th>
                            <th class="section-information-room"><h4>Room</h4></th>
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptSectionDates" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptSectionDates_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phAnd" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                <tr class="section-information-and">
                                    <td colspan="5">
                                        <b>and</b>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <tr class="section-information-content">
                                <td><asp:Literal ID="litDates" runat="server" /></td>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phNonDistanceColumns" runat="server">
                                    <td><asp:Literal ID="litDaysOfWeek" runat="server" /></td>
                                    <td><asp:Literal ID="litTimes" runat="server" /></td>
                                    <td><asp:HyperLink ID="hypBuilding" runat="server" Enabled="false" /></td>
                                    <td><asp:HyperLink ID="hypRoom" runat="server" Enabled="false" /></td>
                                </asp:PlaceHolder>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="section-information-additional-wrapper clearfix">                                                     
                <div class="section-information-additional-left">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>                  
                            <tr class="section-information-additional">
                                <td class="section-infomation-additional-subheader"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTeacher" runat="server" Visible="false"><h4>Teacher: </h4></asp:PlaceHolder></td>
                                <td class="section-infomation-additional-content"><asp:HyperLink ID="hypTeacher" runat="server" Visible="false" /><asp:Literal ID="litTeacher" runat="server" Visible="false" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="section-information-additional">
                                <td class="section-infomation-additional-subheader"><h4>Hours: </h4></td>
                                <td class="section-infomation-additional-content"><%=m_Course.CourseHours.ToString("0.##") %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="section-information-additional">
                                <td class="section-infomation-additional-subheader"><h4>Fee: </h4></td>
                                <td class="section-infomation-additional-content"><asp:Literal ID="litFee" runat="server" /> <asp:Literal ID="litFeeNote" runat="server" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="trSectionNotes" runat="server" visible="false" class="section-information-additional">
                                <td class="section-infomation-additional-subheader"><h4>Note: </h4></td>
                                <td class="section-infomation-additional-content"><%# Eval("SectionNotes") %></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="section-information-additional-right clearfix">
                    <div class="section-icon-wrapper">
                        <span class="blue-button"><asp:Literal ID="litRegistrationLink" runat="server" /></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Back:**

```
protected void rptSectionDates_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        CourseSection section = (CourseSection)e.Item.DataItem;

        if (e.Item.ItemIndex > 0)
        {
            PlaceHolder phAnd = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("phAnd");
            phAnd.Visible = true;
        }

        Literal litDates = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litDates");

        if (section.StartDate.Date.Equals(section.EndDate.Date))
        {
            litDates.Text = section.StartDate.ToString(DATE_FORMAT);
        }
        else
        {
            litDates.Text = string.Concat(
                section.StartDate.ToString(DATE_FORMAT),
                " &#8211; ", 
                section.EndDate.ToString(DATE_FORMAT));
        }

        ...
}
```

Comment: The repeater control populates the `EventArgs` within its code to fire the event. But what does it matter _how_ it gets its data?  What _specifically_ are you looking for?

Comment: Or are you asking how the data gets to the repeater in the first place?  Something is setting the `DataSource` somewhere - either in the markup or in the code-behind.

Comment: I need to examine data that stored inside the `section` variable, so I was going to go further down the pipeline where the values are being changed. They are appearing incorrectly on the view.

Comment: I tried finding `rptSectionDates.DataSource = ...` in the code behind, but no results came up.

Comment: When you debug the code, is rptSectionDates_ItemDataBound actually executed, i.e. is your datagrid filled with data when the user views it? If yes, do you know what the source of the data is (irrespective of how it gets into the grid)?

Comment: @Christoph Yes- thats exactly what I am trying to figure out. I searched the code behind for a DataBind but could not find anything for rptSectionDates. This Repeater is inside another repeater, could it be coming from the first repeater?

Comment: If you can debug the application, put a breakpoint somewhere in rptSectionDates_ItemDataBound and examine the callstack. You should find the place from which the data binding is being done. If you can't debug directly but modify the app, then you could use the StackTrace class to print out or log the stack trace information.

Comment: Ah, you didn't tell us ;-) If the parent repeater is databound, then chances are that the parent will pass on the data binding recursively. The rptSectionDates_ItemDataBound method then would be repeatedly called, once for each item in the list for the parent repeater, and with each call to rptSectionDates_ItemDataBound one of those items would be passed on to the child repeater.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will read up on how to do both debug and also use the StackTrace class.

Comment: Can you extend your code sample to show the parent? Also databinding code for the parent, if it exists.

Comment: Lol I felt bad for pasting too much code, but I guess sometimes its necessary. Thanks for pointing this out. I will try reading more about how recursive data binding works.

Comment: Yes, Will do I will extend it now. Thanks for your help.